# Making a class that will create an entry and pack it in a window

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying for a while now to create a function inside my "menu_item" class that will take in the window i would like to pack an entry to as a param and will do it for me.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

class menu_item:


    def __init__(self, name, menu_name):
        self.window_name = name

        menu_name.add_command(label = name, command = lambda : add_window(self, name))

        def add_window(self, name):
            self.window_name = name
            name = Toplevel(root)
            name.wm_title(self.window_name)
            name.mainloop()

    def add_entry(self, window_name):
        new_f = Frame(window_name)
        new_f.pack()
        entry = ttk.Entry(new_f)
        entry.pack()



root = Tk()
root.option_add('*tearOff', False)
root.wm_title('Cashier Prog')



##### Menu #####

menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)
file = Menu(menubar)
edit = Menu(menubar)
help_ = Menu(menubar)
menubar_list =(file, edit,help_)

for i in menubar_list:
    i = Menu(menubar)
menubar_list_names = ('File', 'Edit', 'Help')

for x in range(len(menubar_list)):
    menubar.add_cascade(menu = menubar_list[x], label = menubar_list_names[x])

### add employee window ###

add_employee = menu_item('Add employee', edit)
add_employee.add_entry(add_employee.window_name())


root.mainloop()
```

I believe the problem is that the window name is a string and so i can't pack the frame and put in an str as a parm.
The question is how can i get around that?

Comment: Can you describe better how you want this to work? You want to give it a string name and have it add an Entry widget to the root and a command in the Menu?

Comment: after creating a menu item (with the '__init__' function in the class) I would like to call the 'add_entry' function, give it the menu item's window name as param, and have it pack the entry it in that window. I get an error because 'self.window_name' is a str and i need to put a window in which i want to place my new entry.

Comment: I see. This has nothing to do with names. You can't pack things into a window until after it's created, and it's not created until you call the add_window function. So you will need to make your 'add_entry' method simply add to a list, and then use that list inside your add_window function when you create the window.

Comment: but i'm the window is created when i create an object of the 'menu_item' class (here:  def __init__(self, name, menu_name):
        self.window_name = name

        menu_name.add_command(label = name, command = lambda : **add_window(self, name)**)   and that happens before i try to add an entry to that window